# Determining distance between two pixels with Python

Tags: python

I am making a script in Python with which I could calculate the distance between 2 pixels on my screen, and later convert it into centimeter.

These not exactly coherent codes have done the job. However upon inspecting it with an actual ruler it is not correct (1cm was measured roughly to be 57 pixels and this translated into 1.24cm according to the code bellow). I have a img_to_dpi.py script because I am working with maps and I am using it on those.

Although I came to suspect that 0.24 difference is 0.25 actually and it probably has to do something with my screen having a setting on 125% or something and that I do not even need the img_to_dpi because that is the dpi of my screen (so far I checked 4 maps and all of them had the same 119.somehting).

Is my code good and if it is does my Display Settings could influence the calculation?

```py
# img_to_dpi
from PIL import Image
image_path = 'Grid maps/Valencia.PNG'
with Image.open(image_path) as img:
    width, height = img.size
    resolution = img.info.get('dpi', (0, 0))

print(f"Dimensions: {width} x {height} pixels")
print(f"Resolution: {resolution[0]} DPI (horizontal) x {resolution[1]} DPI (vertical)")
```

```py
# pixel distance
import math
from pynput import mouse


# Global variables to store the coordinates of two points
point1 = None
point2 = None


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed, listener):
    global point1, point2

    if pressed:
        if point1 is None:
            point1 = (x, y)
            print(f"Point 1 set at: {point1}")
        else:
            point2 = (x, y)
            print(f"Point 2 set at: {point2}")

            # Calculate the distance between the two points
            distance = math.sqrt((point2[0] - point1[0]) ** 2 + (point2[1] - point1[1]) ** 2)
            print(f"Distance between points: {distance} pixels")

            # Stop the listener after the second point is set
            listener.stop()


# Function to start the mouse listener
def start_mouse_listener():
    with mouse.Listener(on_click=lambda x, y, button, pressed: on_click(x, y, button, pressed, listener)) as listener:
        listener.join()

start_mouse_listener()
```

```py
# pixel_to_dpi
def pixels_to_cm(pixels, dpi):
    inches = pixels / dpi
    centimeters = inches * 2.54
    return centimeters

# Example usage:
pixels = 58  # replace with your actual number of pixels
dpi = 119      # replace with the DPI of your image

result = pixels_to_cm(pixels, dpi)
print(f"{pixels} pixels is approximately {result:.2f} centimeters.")
```

Comment: Images just have pixels that can be expresed in pixel density for devices- ppi for screens, dpi for printers. That said, ppi/dpi are affected by screen dimentions. 96 * 1.25 = 120 so screen zoom affects the value

Comment: It's easy to confirm there impact of screen zoom: change your zoom to, say 150, and see if the error is increased accordingly. Them you'll know if you also need zoom level in your script.